# Add Basic Authentification to Header of SOAP Request - WebService

Tags: .net, asmx

I have a c# proxy build from wsdl.
I'm trying to add basic authentication to header of request.
The webservice that I'm trying to call is not in  c#. (php may be)

With fiddler, i can see that "no authorization header is present"

And the result of my calls is  : bad username/password

Here is what I've add to my proxy

```
protected override System.Net.WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri uri){
    System.Net.HttpWebRequest request;
    request = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)base.GetWebRequest(uri);
    if (PreAuthenticate){
       System.Net.NetworkCredential networkCredentials =
       Credentials.GetCredential(uri, "Basic");
       if (networkCredentials != null)
       {
           byte[] credentialBuffer = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding().GetBytesnetworkCredentials.UserName + ":" + networkCredentials.Password);
           request.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic" + Convert.ToBase64String(credentialBuffer);>
       }
       else
       {
           throw new ApplicationException("No network credentials");
      }
   }
   return request;
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't have to work with the headers at all. Just set request.Credentials?

Comment: The designer of this webservice says that it's mandatory to send credentials in the header. I've even tried request.Crendentials.

Comment: Of course the credentials go in the header, but in general, you're not the one who should have to put them there.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem a while back, if you can use WCF i would suggest using that, but if you, like me are not allowed too then you can use this implementation. http://geekswithblogs.net/SunnyCoder/archive/2009/03/15/username-password-amp-ws-security-with-silverlight.aspx

If you try and do a custom xml append you're going to run into all kinds of issues. Use this only if you cannot use WCF. Silverlight supports authentication over HTTPS i believe without WCF, but authentication of plain HTTP was moved to WCF.

Comment: I've got a sample from the designer, made in php. it uses soapclient and $headers

here is a sample 
$headers="<credentials><nsl:username xmlns:nsl=\"$namespace\">password<ns2....
$client->setHeaders($headers)

I've build a Win application to test calls and Fiddler doesn't see anything about crendentials in the header. May be, i should fully rewrite the header like i've seen on few sites.

I'm gonna take a look in WCF